# How to write "I am going to talk about a place that I like"

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice

I am taking a Japanese course and I was told to write a composition about a place I like.
I have currently just finished the first book of Minna no nihongo, which is up to lesson 12.
I am thinking of:
このさくぶんの中で好きなところのことを話します。
Can anyone tell me if this is correct?

Answer (score 2):

I think that 場所 is more appropriate than ところ for your sentence because ところ means not only "place" but also "point" such as "それが彼のよい所なんだ。(That is his good point.)"

Answer (score 2):

I would personally phrase it in the following 2 ways:

> １：この作{さく}文{ぶん}の中{なか}で、（私{わたし}の）好き{すき}な場{ば}所{しょ}について話{はな}していきたいと思{おも}います。- I would like to talk about the place I like in this "essay".

or

> ２：この作{さく}文{ぶん}の中{なか}で、（私{わたし}の）好き{すき}な場{ば}所{しょ}を紹{しょう}介{かい}していきたいと思{おも}います。- I would like to introduce (to the reader) the place I like in this "essay".

I think both are fairly used. I will try to breakdown one of the sentences so you understand how all the bits work.

> この作文の中で - In this essay - Pretty straight forward.

> (私の)好きな場所 - The place I like - It is ok to omit the "I" in Japanese.

> について - About - Nothing to add here.

> 話していきたい - I want to talk / I want to go and talk - it has the nuance of going to(していく). It is the `たい-form` of 話していく（していく).

> と思います - I would like to - したいと思います is polite way to say that you want to / will do something.

Now for the second sentence, the only difference is we are changing 話す for 紹介する, which means to "introduce" and it is used a lot in those situations where you are talking about something you know, but your audience does not. In that case we will just change について話す for を紹介する (していきたいと思います).

Comment: Is it really OK to use 話す to refer to what someone does in a 作文? I can't say for certain that I've never encountered 話す with the meaning of "write about," but it seems very counterintuitive to me, to say the least. For that reason, I much prefer your alternative with 紹介する. (Then again, as a native speaker of English, I'm also very resistant to using "talk about" in this context. Most educated adults would avoid it, though of course "discuss" would be fine.)

Comment: @Nanigashi 作文で「今日は～～について話したいと思います。」とか書いてもまあいいと思いますが、「～～について書きたいと思います・書こうと思います」とかでもいいかなと思います。（「述べたいと思います」でもいいですけどちょっと硬いですね）

Comment: @Nanigashi Yeah, it depends a lot in the language. In my native language we say a lot "This book talks about..." and while most teachers wouldn't say you are wrong for saying "I would like to talk about the place I like in this essay" or something, using "discuss" or "write" would be slightly better.

Chocolateさん、 説明したり、ふりがなを訂正したりしてくれてありがとうございます！

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @Chocolate and Felipe Oliveira!

Answer (score 0):

好きなところについて話します／話す or
好きなところに関して話します／話す

The other guy is right, you can also use 場所 instead of ところ but I personally don't think it makes much difference in a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

In the question you stated that **I am going to talk**, however, in your Japanese translation you simply state this fact, i.e. 話します - I will talk. In Japanese there are two structures which you could use, namely

> 話したい - I want to talk
> 話すつもり - I intent to talk

Next, if you want to talk about something I think that について is more appropriate

> について話すつもり (you could refer to https://www.italki.com/question/270533)

Finally, I would say that your sentence might look like this

> この作文には好きな場所について話したいです

Comment: `この作文は好きな場所について話したいです` would mean 作文 wants to talk. `however, in your Japanese translation you simply state this fact, i.e. 話します` 「話します。」（または「書きます。」）でもまあいいと思いますが。`In Japanese there are two structures...` 「話そうと思います。」も使えますよ。「話したいです。」より「話したいと思います。」のほうがいいですね。（または「書こうと思います。」「書きたいと思います。」)

Comment: @Chocolate thanks for the review, taking the context into account that it is a person who speaks, wouldn't `この作文は...` mean `as for the composition...`, or is it better to state `私、僕、あたし` explicitly? Or `この作文には`? Using 話そう (let's talk) does sound good to me